# save an xml file

Tags: php

I wonder how I can learn to get the location where a particular xml is created and save as follows,

```
  $document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    ....//write things to it
    echo $document->saveXML();
```

How do I know where it is saved ? as stream or as a binary file ? anywhere on teh HD I can get or view it ?                                                                                                    I don't know why the red message below says that my post doesn't meet our quality standard. My post is short but understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, [`saveXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) not "saves" the document on HD, but rather just returns the string representation of XML document to you. In order to write your document to HD, you should use [`save($filename)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just refer the documentation

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php

```
int DOMDocument::save ( string $filename [, int $options ] )

filename

    The path to the saved XML document.
options

    Additional Options. Currently only LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG is supported.
```

Check the example

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
// we want a nice output
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->createElement('book');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$title = $doc->createElement('title');
$title = $root->appendChild($title);

$text = $doc->createTextNode('This is the title');
$text = $title->appendChild($text);

echo 'Wrote: ' . $doc->save("/tmp/test.xml") . ' bytes'; // Wrote: 72 bytes

?>
```